# Print float values of a struct

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>      

struct testStruct
{
    int max;
    float y;
    float x;
};

int main()
{
    struct testStruct test;

    test.max = 50;
    test.y = 0.001;
    test.x = 0.05;
    printf("%i\n", test.max);
    printf("%i\n", test.x);
    printf("%i\n", test.y);
}
```

I created a struct with `int` and `float` values. When i print the values for some reason the two `float` values print some junk value like 3539983 instead of their respective values. Can anyone please explain why this is? The `int` value prints correctly.

Comment: your are using the wrong format specifier for your floats, see here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: You should use one of  `%f`, `%g` or `%e` to print floating-point values. `%i` and `%d` are for signed integers. Turn on compiler warnings; you will usually get warnings on format mismatches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fix your specifiers within the `printf` to:

```
printf("%d\n",test.max);
printf("%f\n",test.x);
printf("%f\n",test.y);
```

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf).

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%i\n",test.max);
printf("%i\n",test.x);
printf("%i\n",test.y);
```

should be

```
printf("%d\n",test.max);
printf("%f\n",test.x);
printf("%f\n",test.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

%d and %i is the same when used in output.
change

```
printf("%f\n",test.x);
printf("%f\n",test.y);
```

for print your desired result